# React axios post error: "Request failed with status code 400"

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I am creating a front-end app in react with the back-end in **django** and using **djangorestframework**. Here I am working on plain form submission by calling an API endpoint. I am using **axios** to make the post request. I have put the axios method withing handleSubmit() method:

```
handleSubmit(event){
event.preventDefault();

const data = {
   first_name: this.state.first_name,
   last_name: this.state.last_name,
   dob: this.state.dob,
   sex: this.state.sex
 };

axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/create/', data)
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

On the back-end i am using the `generics.CreateAPIView` view:

```
class CreateProfile(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

The url: `path('profile/create/', CreateProfile.as_view()),`

The models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
    TRANS = 'T'
    NO_MENTION = 'NO'
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
        (TRANS, 'Trans'),
        (NO_MENTION, 'Rather not say')
    ]
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

When I am submitting the form this error is showing in the console: `Error: "Request failed with status code 400"`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which status code was in the error message? [`404`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) or [`400`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)? `404` is for not found one, `400` is for bad request. Thanks!

Comment: Status code is 400.

Comment: Have you attempted to use DRF api functionality to try the endpoint?

Comment: Yes, is calling a createAPIView endpoint through axios.post

Comment: No, I mean by typing the url directly on your browser

Comment: Yes, I  tried both by trying the URL on the browser and using postman. Both worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by changing the date format in the date input field of the form. As per *Django REST framework*, the date format is **YYYY-MM-DD**. Therefore, I had to insert date as `type="text"` in the same format and it solved the error.

Status code 400 means Bad request. That is, an error has been made by the client side. So observing whether the input format in the client side matches with that required in the api endpoint is very important.

Answer (score 0):

`400` hints at possible invalid form data. Make sure you have included all models fields in your form data, that are not nullable as per your model definition. Also other constraints could be affected. If you share your model, that would make things a lot easier.

However, and this is more like, your request is blocked because of CORS protection.

Install django-cors via

`pip install django-cors-headers`

and then in your settings.py

add or rather append

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

as well as

```
MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

and define your CORS whitelist something like this

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
]
```

Have a look at the docs on [django-cors-headers here](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/).

Comment: These are all properly configured. I think the issue is coming from the view. Could it be?

Comment: could be... share your view and model please. That would easen things.

Comment: check your console where you're running your `python manage.py runserver`. It should give you more details and let us know.

Comment: The python console returned this: `Bad Request: /profile/create/
[14/May/2020 00:00:24] "POST /profile/create/ HTTP/1.1" 400 118`

Comment: Add ‚DEBUG = True‘ to your settings.py. That should give you more details.